How do I fix file_put_contents error in Laravel?
I'm trying to deploy my Laravel website. and it shows this error. It works totally fine in local machine but showing this error when I hosted it.

file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\students-app\storage\framework/sessions/EDrmElizDsvoYNGB9sjH7XpuxfxCj1ZQoo8Rw9cx): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory



Hmm, it should have created some of that folder structure for you. Work your way up the directory structure and tell us which bit does exist please.
